# I need a formula that finds the duplicates in column a and then checks in column b if the status are the same

Tags: excel

[image]

Hello,
I am trying to find the correct formula (excel 2016) that would recognize duplicate values in column A and then checks in column B if they have the same status or not and bring the result same not same.

Comment: Look into COUNTIFS

Answer (score 1):

In F2 put `=A2=A3` and copy down.
Then in G2 put `=AND(F2,B2=B3)` and copy down.
Then in H2 put `=IF(G2,"Same", "Not Same")` and copy down.

If you want to combine into fewer columns, feel free, but I separated it out here to make easier for anybody new to understand.

Comment: Thank you, i managed to solve this part. Maybe you can help me with another issue i m facing. In column a i have currency (in the form or eur, nok, gbp etc) in column b i have the amounts. And i want in column c to bring all amounts in eur which means if in column a is eur then it equals with column b, if it is nok then =column b/10.25 and so on. Any suggestion?

Comment: Do set that up as a separate question.